# Microsoft Office updates fail to install

Tags: wsus, update, microsoft-office, windows-installer

I have one computer (Windows XP) which is updating via update services.  Most updates are installing successfully, however updates to MS Office are failing to install.  Windows updates then pops up again with the list of pending office updates still listed.  Repeated attempts to install the updates fail again.

Comment: +1. This seems like a reasonable sysadmin question. If I may make a suggestion: Consider rewording the subject to be in a more focused format, such as how to re-enable Office updates which are not applying. Also, consider giving more details about what it means when "installation fails."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a problem with the windows installer service.  Resolve by command line:

```
msiexec /unregister
msiexec /regserver
```